# Clear content in textbox onclick of image

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help here for clearing the contents in textbox. I have tried to clear the contents in text box on click of an image using javascript

```
<input name="newKey" id="newKey" type="text" value="helo" size="38" maxlength="45"/>
<span class="btnClr" id="clear" onclick=clearThis("newKey"></span>


function clearThis(target){
    target.value= "";
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fRB/222/

Comment: please show your code

Comment: Stop giving negative vote. Its the place where people can learn & moreover the jsfiddle is given to show what is being tried. Its not being simple question without trying anything!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are clearing a string called 'target' :)

What you want to clear is the DOM element itself:

```
function clearThis(target) {
    target = document.getElementById(target);
    target.value = "";
}
```

Moreover, your `onclick` attribute needed quoting to not be ambiguous:

```
onclick='clearThis("search")'
```

#### [Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMrUb/)

---

On another note, consider using less obtrusive JavaScript. It is easier to maintain and develop. Debugging code inside attribute strings can be a real nightmare, and might create portability issues.

Something like:

```
var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
var search = document.getElementById("search");

function clearThis(element) {
    element.value = "";
}

clear.onclick = function(){
    clearThis(search);    
}
```

And no JavaScript in your HTML

[Here is a fiddle of that](http://jsfiddle.net/yQEcR/)

Comment: thnx,it works - i want to hide the image(clear) till the user type

Comment: @user2353513 Generally, questions in SO should not include other questions because it'll be confusing to future visitors - however let me get you started: Sure, there are two things you can do about it. First, I'll tell you that elements have a `.style` property, and setting `.style.display` to hidden hides an element. Moreover, inputs have a keyup event you can hook on. You can see how the two mix and build it yourself. If you aren't able to really figure it out your second option is to ask another question here - just be sure to include your attempts :) Good luck and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

USE GET ELEMENT BY ID.....http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fRB/230/

```
function clearThis(target){


        document.getElementById(target).value= "";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**[working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7fRB/227/)**

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
    $("#newKey").val('');
});
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the asker's jsfiddle says jQuery 1.5.2

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can u check asker's jsfiddle

Comment: @JanDvorak But his question is not tagged with jQuery, and his code does not use jQuery. That's adding thousands of lines of code for no reason.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum should I add the tag based on the fiddle?

Comment: but yeah, OP doesn't seem to actually use jQuery, in which case adding it would be kinda pointless.

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course not, for all we know OP could have forked a fiddle who happened to use jQuery and just forgot to remove it. It looks like he played with the settings. What matters here is his _question_ and the code in the question. Neither of which say _anything_ about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this

```
function clearThis(target){
    document.getElementById(target).value = "";

    }
```